# PHPunit takes lot of time to boot on Homestead hence resulting in slow tests

Tags: performance, laravel, phpunit, vagrant, homestead

I have created a basic [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/) application and I try to run few tests using PHPUnit.

When I run a simple call to phpunit in my local terminal it takes about 120ms for the tests to be completed. However, when I run the same call in [homestead machine](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead) (vagrant) it takes more than 3seconds(!) to complete! That's insane.

I've done some testing and it seems that the tests them self aren't slow it just that phpunit is super slow to boot on homestead. I guess it might be slow for homestead to execute the phpunit executable? The same is true for composer which is much slower ran on homestead than on my local terminal, but it is not as slow as phpunit in terms of percentages.

Any idea how I can fix this "delay" and make phpunit tests run fast on homestead as-well?

Answer (score 2):

is due the filesystem used to mount Windows' Folders on homestead.

Homestead is managed by Vagrant that uses VirtualBox to launch Virtual Machines, and Virtual Box use vboxsf as a file system, I don't know why but this is too slow to run PHPUnit.

I guess you have your code on the windows' folders and reach it from homestead using the standard shared folder provided by Vagrant/VirtualBox.(That is my case)

I mounted a Windows Shared Folder (my code is there) using CIFS as a file system and reduced the execution time of my tests from 58.46s to 6.51s.

Here you find the indications to this:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't allocated a lot of resources to your VM. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190330/how-do-i-improve-the-performance-of-my-virtualbox-guest) answer helpful.

> A virtual guest with that low of resources will run slowly. For best performance you actually give your host a bit more resources than the guest. Also you will not be able to give both cpu's to your virtual machine since your host machine needs something to run everything. Think of it this way. Your host machine has to run its' own system plus the container for the guest. The guest gets into a resource fight with the host machine. Try giving the guest less and see how it runs.

I use Virtual Box along with Vagrant and this [post](http://lifehacker.com/the-power-users-guide-to-better-virtual-machines-in-vir-1569943402) explains the quickest way to power up your VM through the Virtual Box UI. The better way is to edit your [VagrantFile](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html) which so that every time you vagrant up your Laravel Homestead box, it sets the configs the way you want them.

UPDATE: Hmm. I'm running `PHPSpec` in a VM to test some custom checkout methods on an ecommerce site. In PHPSpec my first test was taking about `10000ms` no matter what it tested. The two things I did were to enable caches which I usually have off while developing and edited the Vagrant config to juice up the box:

```
config.vm.define :web, primary: true do |web|
  web.vm.hostname = "web"
  web.vm.box = "trusty64" 
  web.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 2048
        v.cpus   = 4
  end
end
```

This dropped the total run time of the tests about 25% and that first test dropped to about `1500ms`.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for your answer. I'm running the homestead(vagrant) box on a Mackbook Pro 2014 with 16GB RAN and a quad-core CPU. I've allocated 2GB of ram to the VM and 2 CPU cores. I've ran `top` in my VM to see what is the CPU usage when I run `phpunit` and the CPU usage is 2-4% only. I've also monitored my PHPUnit tests execution time and they are fast. I've added many more tests and they ran at approx 600ms. The rest of the time is to PHPUnit to load. It take 2.5-3s until I see the `phpunit 4.7.7 by Sebastian...` from there it's very quick. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm. I'm running `PHPSpec` in a VM to test some custom checkout methods on an ecommerce site. In PHPSpec my first test was taking about `10000ms` no matter what it tested. The two things I did were to enable caches which I usually have off while developing and add the lines ` web.vm.box = "trusty64"` and `web.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 1024
        v.cpus   = 2
    end`

Comment: SpaceJam9 the tests themselves aren't slow. I've allocated 2 cpu cores and 2gb of ram to the VM as stated above. The slowest test takes 500MS. All of the tests together takes up to 700MS in my local terminal but around 3-4seconds on vm terminal

Comment: Yeah, I get that, only sharing what helped me. There is something about the execution that takes a bit of time.